# Simulating Adhesive Robotics Interactions

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, simulator

I'm currently working on a project where I need to simulate robotic interactions (using ROS/ROS2) with adhesive or sticky materials. (The goal is to peel a sticker using a robot arm) I'm a bit familiar with Gazebo, but I'm unsure how to implement it. Does anyone have experience with this and can offer some guidance or point me towards useful tutorials?

Additionally, if you've successfully used other simulators for similar adhesive-related tasks, I'd be eager to learn about your experiences and any recommendations you might have.

Thanks